# Splitting a jQuery DatePicker into hidden fields

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

We have a PHP booking system that by using 6 drop lists sends 6 hidden variables to the results page for a date search.

start_day, start_month, start_year, end_day, end_month, end_year

I would however like to use 2 jQuery datepickers and lets say for sake of argument they are set up with the following date formatting.

```
$( "datefrom_picker" ).datepicker( "option", "getDate", "dd-mm-yy" );
$( "datefrom_picker2" ).datepicker( "option", "getDate", "dd-mm-yy" );
```

My question is is there a way of splitting the jQuery datepicker date format so that it can send the six date parts to the results page? For example i have attempted probably badly to figure this out for the first calendar..

The hidden form fields:

```
<input name="start_month" id="start_month" type="hidden" value="" />
<input name="start_day" id="start_day" type="hidden" value="" />
<input name="start_year" id="start_year" type="hidden" value="" />
```

The jQuery

```
$( "#datefrom_picker" ).datepicker( "option", "getDate", "dd-mm-yy" );
      toDateModComboFlights = ($('#datefrom_picker').datepicker("getDate"));
        if (toDateModComboFlights!=null) {
            document.forms['frmCheckAvailability'].elements['start_day'].value = toDateModComboFlights.dd();
            document.forms['frmCheckAvailability'].elements['start_month'].value = toDateModComboFlights.mm();
            document.forms['frmCheckAvailability'].elements['start_year'].value = toDateModComboFlights.yy();
}
```

Thanks for any help in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `onClose` option of the datepicker so that each time a date is chosen the hidden fields are updated.  You said you have 6 hidden fields but you only show 3. I'm guessing the missing ones are "end_month" and so on.

Initialize the datepicker and create a function like so

```
 $( "#datefrom_picker" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy",
    onClose: function(dateText) {
      //dateText is a string matching your desired format
      var dateParts = dateText.split("-");//spilts string using dash

      //now set each input field (you can figure out the other three)
      $('#start_month').val(dateParts[0]);
      $('#start_day').val(dateParts[1]);
      $('#start_year').val(dateParts[2]);
    },

 });
```

you can setup the second datepicker in the same exact way but reference the other hidden values instead.

Comment: Object [object Date] has no method 'split'